# Backbone.js - Object doesn't support property or method 'each'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm very inexperienced with Backbone, but have inherited another dev's code to maintain. I'm trying to add some new functionality to a model. Here's what I have so far:

```
    var AfeDetailCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend(
    {
        model: AfeDetailModel,
        getSubtotalUSD: function(){
            return _.reduce(this.models, function(memo, model, index, list){
                return memo + model.getExtCostUSD();
            }, 0, this);
        },
        getSubtotalLocal: function () {
            return _.reduce(this.models, function (memo, model, index, list) {
                return memo + model.getExtCostLocal();
            }, 0, this);
        },
        hasMixedCurrency: function () {
            var currCode = '';
            this.models.each(function (model) {
                if (currCode == '')
                    // Identify the currencyCode of the first AfeDetail object in the collection
                    currCode = model.get('currencyCode');
                else if (currCode != model.get('currencyCode'))
                    // The currencyCode has changed from prior AfeDetail in the collection
                    return true;
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
);
```

The hasMixedCurrency() function is what I've added. The two pre-existing functions work fine. What I'm trying to do is determine whether the collection of AfeDetail objects contains multiple currencyCode values (a property on the AfeDetail model). So I was simply trying to iterate through this collection until I find a change in the currencyCode and then return true.

In the javascript on my page, however, as soon as I try to check this...

```
if (this.collection.hasMixedCurrency()) {
   ...
```

...I get this: *Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'each'*

I'm obviously doing something wrong, probably something simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: There is no such method called `each` for JS array afaik... try `this.each`, `this` being reference to collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is look like **this.models** is a **javascript array**, not a **backbone collection**.

You can try with **underscore**'s each method:

```
_.each(arr, function(val) { 

});
```

Also your logic in loop looks wrong. Try this code:

```
hasMixedCurrency: function() {
    return _.size(_.uniq(this.models, "currencyCode")) > 1;
}
```

> **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/L8r4pgxd/)**

---

> **Edit:** More performanced way

```
hasMixedCurrency: function () {
    return _.find(this.models, function(v) { return v.currencyCode !== _.first(this.models).currencyCode; }) !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: It is a JavaScript array, which doesn't have an `each` method. BTW if it was a collection `each` would work because it does have an `each` method.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made a mistake while writing. Sorry for this.

Comment: I guess I need to dig into this more to understand the difference between what's a JS array and what's a Backbone collection. Anyway, your code sample did the trick! @ibrahimyilmaz

Comment: Actually, upon closer examination, this code isn't working just right. It's returning True every time. The only time it should return true is when the array contains more than one currencyCode value. I'll continue playing around with it.

Comment: Yes, @PongGod you're right too :) Check my edited answer and try fiddle above.

Comment: I'm not seeing any output when I run your Fiddle. BTW, I began taking a different approach which I thought was going to work, but it's still not quite there yet. Perhaps you can take a look and let me know what you think: https://jsfiddle.net/PongGod/6qvz2p94/3

Comment: Actually, a simple adjustment to your code gets it right:

return _.size(_.uniq(this.models, "currencyCode")) > 1;

No need to compare against the size of the array. Quite simply, if more than one currencyCode value appears in the array, then it should return true. If you can edit your above code accordingly, I'll accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: You are wrong. _.uniq function returns same array without duplicate values. So size of _.uniq() for both array1 and array2 is 3. See fiddle again, i'm writing to html now.

Comment: Also your fiddle is not valid. You can't compare only first and last values of array. Duplciate values may be in the middle.

Comment: Regarding my fiddle, perhaps you didn't notice that I sorted the values before doing the comparison. The example works, but unfortunately I was having difficulty adapting it successfully to my application. However, when I changed your above code the way I described, it did begin working correctly.

Regarding your updated fiddle, I can't see the output in the console section. In any case, all three arrays contain mixed currencies so I'm not sure how this proves it works. Sure, I can edit one of them to only include a single currency, but I'm still unable to see the output when I run it.

Comment: I have added screenshot of jsFiddle screen. Anyway, your fiddle is still wrong try and think about it.

Comment: The logic in my fiddle is not wrong. If you have an array of strings and sort them alphabetically, compare the first and last values and find that they are the same, then you know with certainty that there are no differing values in between. In any case, I already abandoned that approach in favor of yours with the minor modification I described and it works. I greatly appreciate your assistance and will gladly mark it as the solution if you update it accordingly. As that code currently stands, it doesn't work as a solution for me.

Comment: BTW, your fiddle is the one that's wrong. All three of those array examples should return True because they all have mixed currencies. If one of then only included "USD" values, for example, then it should return False. Perhaps you've been misunderstanding my requirements, but I think I've explained it quite clearly.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought you wanted to find duplicate values. You're right.

Comment: If you edit your answer above to: .size(.uniq(this.models, "currencyCode")) > 1; I can accept it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited it and added more kind (high performance) method too. We don't have to make array unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186748/discussion-between-ponggod-and-ibrahimyilmaz).